# Getting NoSuchEntityException when trying to connect Magento 2 store to ebay

Tags: magento2, error, m2e, m2epro, ebay

I recently used M2E pro to migrate our ebay orders from our Magento 1 site to our Magento 2 site and I'm now getting some problems with the M2E system.

Firstly we're getting an error at the top of the page reading:

> M2E Pro Health Status Notification: Something went wrong with your M2E
>   Pro running and some actions from your side are required. A detailed
>   information you can find in M2E Pro Health Status Center.

The health center shows the following two problems:

> eBay Retrieving It seems that there were no orders imported into your
>   M2E Pro during the latest 24 hours which is rather unusual. We
>   strongly recommend you to ensure that there were purchases made on
>   Channel. If the purchases are available on Channel, there might be
>   some issue with your Module running (e.g. failed Install/Upgrade
>   processes, incorrect settings for Magento Cron and inability to use
>   M2E Pro Cron Service, lost connection to M2E Pro Servers, error
>   returned from Channel for Account access, etc.). Thus, please, verify
>   all the aspects related to the Installation/Upgrade and configuration
>   of your M2E Pro Module. It might be helpful to involve your
>   Developer/Administrator into this process along with surfing
>   theDocumentation and Knowledge Base. In case, any assistance is
>   needed, you can consult with our Support Team via
>   email support@m2epro.com.
>
> eBay Magento Order Creation During the last 24 hours, M2E Pro could
>   not create Magento orders for 24 imported Channel orders due to
>   unforeseen issues on Magento side. Please check the Order Logs for
>   more details.

When we click on M2E Pro in "Ebay Integration" and "Listings" We get an error beginning with the following:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsitename.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(167): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById(5)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsitename.com/httpdocs/app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Block/Adminhtml/Ebay/Listing/Grid.php(262): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore(5)
```

As the error mentions getById(5) and getStore(5) I wondered if this had anything to do with the fact that the Ebay store has the following identifiers:

- 6 for the group ID
- 6 for the website ID
- 11 for the default store ID

If this is the case how would we go about changing this so that the ebay system synchronizes with Magento properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have spoken to support@m2epro.com.

There was a problem with a removed/not created Store in Magento, which M2E uses in Listings.

They fixed it remotely and changed on default store. It all seems to be working now.